# what is a word that describes a group of related words

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word that represents a group of words. In this case the group of words are meal types, like:

- dessert
- dinner
- feast
- picnic
- refreshment
- snack
- etc..

Is there a single word that is an alternative for "meal types"?
Or if no such word exists a more elegant phrasing?

Comment: No, not really. When you think about it, there are kazillions of things that can be grouped, but there aren't kazillions of English words. Only the words that everybody uses most of the time get learned by everybody, so if there were such a word, it would be rare or archaic, and if you used it, very few people would understand you.

Comment: The word would be an  ***umbrella term:***  word that groups other words into a single common category. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/umbrella-term

Comment: Alright, thanks for both the explanation and the suggestion! So in the case of the umbrella example (heart disease). Is there such word for my case?

Comment: Food and beverage ?

Comment: @Hachi that is a bit too general since I only want to target moments of eating like a snack, dinner, lunch etc.

Comment: @FutureCake, *So in the case of the umbrella example (heart disease). Is there such word for my case?* -> **Umbrella term** is not only used for 'heart diseases' (the dictionary has only used 'heart diseases' as an example of 'umbrella term'). It is a general term and can be applied to every group of things.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I know, but what I meant is that "heart diseases" is an umbrella term for all kind of heart problems. So is there a word or words like "heart diseases" that could function as an umbrella term for my group of words?

Comment: @Hachi has already said that. 'Food and beverages'. (I don't think there's any other word for that.)

Comment: How about just *Meals*. You don't need *Types*. Compare *Heart Diseases* — it's not *Heart Disease Types*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yeah this is about what I was looking for thanks! Post it as an answer if you want and I will accept it.

Comment: @JohnLawler If I understand you rightly, you are saying that there _is_ no "taxonomy" of words that classifies them by the things that they represent? It would be a kind of "meta"-taxonomy, no?

Comment: Taxonomies are abstract classifications, not English words. Anybody can make up a taxonomy of anything based on any categorization they please, and label everything with their own constructed labels. People do it all the time. It's just that nobody ever does it quite the same way, or uses quite the same terminology, so there are too  many taxonomies, and **way** too many technical terms to choose from. It's rather like the situation with grammatical rules.

Comment: Following @KannE, it's not clear that refreshments are meals either, or that a feast or picnic would not include dessert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just *Meals*?

You don't need *Types*.

Compare the example at [umbrella term](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/umbrella-term): *Heart Diseases* — it's not *Heart Disease Types*

*Menus* might work as well—sort of a double play: A menu of menus (drinks menu, dinner menu, picnic menu . . .)

Comment: They'll do, in the right contexts. None of these are exactly the same; _meals_ can be (and usually are) individual events, with participants, and/or the foods at the meal. _Menus_ are texts containing the names of the foods (not the foods themselves), and can metaphorically stand for the foods, though not the events, and you still have different types of menus (table d'hote and happy hour, for instance).

Comment: Yes, @JohnLawler, now that I think about this, these all might be tags, not categories. Sandwich might appear in Lunch and Picnic. Drinks might appear, well, everywhere. The heading would be *Tagged* or some such.